# Why is there so much time in between animation code and next animation frame?

Tags: performance, animation, canvas

I'm implementing a game using a canvas as the renderer, and there are some points where there seem to be excessive "waits" between render frames and I have no idea what to think of this.

I've been working on this for the past few weeks and for the most part, there haven't really been issues. However, when there are a lot of things on screen there is a "wait" for some reason.

[image: performance metrics]

It takes about the same amount of time that the rendering code does before "composite layers" is called. I don't know if this is something that I can prevent or if it is just something that I have to live with. I'm only getting to the point where I'm going below 60 fps in extreme situations anyway.

Another example: 
[image: another example]
index.js

```
window.onload = () => {
    const width = 1280;
    const height = 720;
    const canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function renderLoop() {
        console.time("render");
        // Do render and request next frame
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (let i = 0; i < 13000; i++) {
            // Not real code this is just to demonstrate the issue
            ctx.fillRect(i % width, 10 * Math.floor(i / (width)), 10, 10);
        }

        console.timeEnd("render");
        requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      canvas {
        border: 2px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <canvas id="game-canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try to set up a live [mcve] please? Are you using a framework like react? You said "*I'm only getting to the point where I'm going below 60 fps in extreme situations anyway.*" but here it seems each frame took about 80ms, that's 12.5FPS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yea I'll get around to doing that. I'll try to create a reproducible example.

And no I'm not using react. It is just a canvas no libraries. I don't know how that could make a difference though. Considering that I don't think that the animation frame is effected by anything but itself. 

That was another confusing thing too, I was running at around 50 fps at the time of the screenshot. I'll see if I can update that as well.

Comment: The thing I'm interested in is why there is so much idle time when the canvas could still be updated at 60fps

Comment: Or rather what is this "system" time: https://i.imgur.com/Og0aiMV.png